# Getting "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist" but listener exists

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So i am trying to send a message from the background.js script to a content script but i get this error `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist`.

background.js

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {data: {
        message: 'createProfileFrame',
        userData: userData
    }}, function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
})
```

popup.js (content script)

```js
const framesContainer = document.getElementById('framesContainer');

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request);
    sendResponse(true);
    if (request.data.message == 'createProfileFrame') {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.style.display = 'block';

        const frame = document.createElement('div');
        frame.style.backgroundColor = 'white',
        frame.style.borderRadius = '20px';
        frame.style.width = '90%';
        frame.style.height = '3rem';
        li.appendChild(frame);
        
        framesContainer.appendChild(li);
    }
})
```

popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <ul id="framesContainer"></ul>
        </div>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Extension",
    "description": "Test extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "cookies",
        "webRequest"
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

I read the documentation multiple times and to me it looks like everything correct so i don't know what i am doing wrong, i would appreciate any help.

Comment: 1) The popup is not a content script. The popup usually means the page declared via `browser_action` or `action` in manifest.json, so it's not related to web page where your content scripts run. The popup runs only when shown so it can't receive messages when not shown. To send to a content script you need to declare it or inject it. Also, you need to make sure the content script runs in the tab at the moment of sending. 2) Is it the entire code of background.js or is it inside some `chrome` event listener?

Comment: 1) It's not popup.html that is listening to the request but popup.json. i forgot to include the code of popup.html and manifest.json so maybe now it's more clear. the code runs when the current tab is focused because the cookie changed event is fired after a login so the user has the tab focused
2) no it's not the full code of background.js and yes it runs in a chrome event but how does that matter? it is inside chrome.cookies.onChanged

Comment: Okay, to send a message to a popup use chrome.**runtime**.sendMessage without a tab id, but note that it will work only when the popup is shown.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't want to send the message to popup.html but to popup.js

Comment: There's no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the call to `sendMessage()` was being done before the listener of the content script could load, adding a timeout to the call fixed the issue.

Comment: How did you add the timeout?

Comment: setTimeout(function () {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {data: {
        message: 'createProfileFrame',
        userData: userData
    }}, function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
    }, 1000); // Delay of 1 second (adjust as needed)